# 503 responses from Azure FrontDoor with AKS backend where host header is required

Tags: dns, url-routing, azure-aks, azure-front-door

We have an Azure FrontDoor (FD) configuration (backend pool and routing setup for https) that is returning 503 for our site that is hosted in a container in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

We have an Azure front door configured to route to a backend that's hosted in AKS.  The backend has an address of https://application-eastus2-01.application.com.  We have configured the host header to send as [www.application.com](http://www.application.com). I.e. it is different to the backend address.

We have setup the AKS to serve our website via a container and ingress if the host header [www.application.com](http://www.application.com) is used.  If i run curl and postman against this AKS ingress ip and send the host header [www.application.com](http://www.application.com) in the request, it responds correctly with the site content. When i make the request to the address directly (from curl or postman  wieh the correct host header), the site responds almosts immediately (i.e. it takes less than a second). I.e. i don't think this is a FrontDoor time out issue.

We have configured an FD backend pool so that the host header [www.application.com](http://www.application.com) is sent for requests to this backend ( https://application-eastus2-01.application.com).  However, when i attempt to access https://www.application.com which is the address that is routed through FrontDoor for this DNS, FD responds with a 503 status.  I don't think this is related to a timeout issue unless something else is misconfigured.

In looking at this Azure Monitor logs, it looks like everything is configured correctly.

I've studied this MS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-troubleshoot-routing

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing the 503 response.  What else can we try to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with a self certificate.  it seems AFD needs to have a certificate on the backend and the container that is valid and publically CA secured. The means, on the default backend and the app being served.

Comment: Does this mean AFD won't work if backend has a LetsEncrypt issued cert?

Comment: @ShahidSyed did you find the answer for your question? Can you please share?

Comment: @AmitPattnaik I had to disable 'require https' on Azure web app for it to work. In my case the website does not deal with any sensitive information so its fine if someone uses http instead of https.

Comment: @ShahidSyed I am also getting this random 503 server errors. Can I check with you 

Previously, were your Frontend using the managed certificate from Front Door managed and your Backend were using your own certificate? 

I am thinking whether both frontend and backend need to have the same certificate.

Comment: @AmitPattnaik Any solutions to share?

Comment: I'm not sure about letencrypt.  We ended up procuring a wildcard certificate for the services we were running.  The other option of course is to use AFD's own certificate management capabilities.

Comment: @DANLEE For www subdomain I used AFD managed certificate. For root I used my wildcard letsencrypt certificate. On web app I have the same letsencrypt certificate.
Later I converted my website to Blazor WASM and it didn't work with AFD so got rid of it and used the money for P2v2 app plan.

Comment: @ossentoo just checking, were your getting momentarily random 503 errors in your case or it a 503 errors from the start?